# Build on Azure Web App, Error:Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6'

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have a asp.net core web project that was continuous deployed to Azure well.
After I added another .net core class library to the solution, it gives the following build error on Azure: Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): error : Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win8-x86, win7-x86'.

However, the solution builds and runs successfully on local box.

Any one experience that before

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: Maybe because you locally run x64 while Azure is x86?

Comment: tried to set the azure web app to 64bit, not really fix the issue

Comment: azure runs 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error as well in the same situation and the problem ended up being the MSBuild arguments I was using to enable the creation of a WebDeploy package.  I was using the `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` argument when I saw this.

I was able to work around it by calling the `PackagePublish` target with MSBuild instead.  For example,

```
D:\GitHub\AcmeApp.NET\src\AcmeApp.NET.Web>"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild" /t:PackagePublish /p:PublishProfile=Package
```

You can find more details on the following blog post - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/09/20/webdeploy-packaging-with-asp-net-core/